# Mean Without Failure Rate For Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose X is an exponential random variable with P(X<4.19)=0.632

How do I find the mean of X with just this information?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ and the equality in your question enables you to find $\lambda$.
- $\mathbb EX=\frac1{\lambda}$